# How to pass a precodition value for a job in Github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions, jobs

I want to pass a value from a job to another. The output will be a precondition for the next job so if the value will be false the next job will not run.

I've seen that there is a solution for this with ::set-output, but this feature will be deprecated.

I want to achieve something like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  check-version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
        if: ${{ condition }}
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=CONTINUE::false"

  deploy:
    if: ${{ needs.check-version.outputs.CONTINUE != 'false' }}
    needs: [check-version]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "The job is running"
```

Comment: See [setting an output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) and [defining outputs for jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs).

Comment: What have you tried? What prevents you doing it as documented? Please read the announcement **[GitHub Actions: Deprecating save-state and set-output commands](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/)**  and follow the instructions to handle the deprecation (also do what @Azeem wrote).

Comment: I've also tried to set it as an output parameter but I get: `Unrecognized named-value: 'steps'. Located at position 1 within expression: steps.check-version.outputs.CONTINUE`.

Comment: @Valentin: Double check with the documentation, the diagnostic message tells you where the error is and what went wrong.Or in short: read the resources Azeem linked to learn how it is done (`id` **!!**, `outputs` **!!**, `needs` **!!**, the documentation has a whole "learn" section as well if you're new to Microsoft Github Actions).

Comment: You need to first define outputs for job. Reference [Defining outputs for jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to all the references shared with you in the comments:

- [GitHub Actions: Deprecating save-state and set-output commands](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/)
- [Setting an output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter)
- [Defining outputs for jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs)

Your workflow should look like this:

```
jobs:
  check-version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      continue: ${{ steps.check.outputs.continue }}
    steps:
      - name: Check Version step
        if: ${{ condition }}
        id: check
        run: echo "continue=false" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  deploy:
    needs: [check-version]
    if: ${{ needs.check-version.outputs.continue != 'false' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "The job is running"
```